# Why is the number of ticks inaccurate?

Tags: cpu, proc, time, stat, clock

I checked the numbers in [proc/stat](https://github.com/Leo-G/DevopsWiki/wiki/How-Linux-CPU-Usage-Time-and-Percentage-is-calculated) to the the number of clock ticks the CPU has had and I saw that the sum of the numbers in CPU1-4 is not equal to the numbers written in front of CPU as a whole. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference results from truncating the values after calculating the sums. [`/proc/stat`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/stat.c#n82) calculates the sums of elapsed times in nanoseconds, and then converts the resulting values to `USER_HZ` using [integer division](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/time.c#n779) which truncates.

Thus if all four CPUs have individual values of 1.3, you’ll get a sum of 5.2, truncated to 5 for the first line, and 1 for each CPU line.